# Class Inheritance - multiple class types in a dictionary

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand why zList["B"].Value does not print 555.666 in the below example.

I'm trying to create a dictionary of classes that could return different types, but I'm not quite sure how to go about doing so.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Dictionary<string, BaseClass> zList = new Dictionary<string, BaseClass>();
            ClassA zA = new ClassA();
            zA.Value = "Test";
            zList["A"] = zA;

            ClassB zB = new ClassB();
            zB.Value = 555.666;
            zList["B"] = zB;


            Console.WriteLine(zList["A"].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(zList["B"].Value);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        private string _value;

        public string Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }
    }

    public class ClassA : BaseClass
    {

    }

    public class ClassB : BaseClass
    {
        private new double _value;

        public new double Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set { _value = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does `zList["B"].Value` print instead?

Comment: I believe the value will be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand why zList["B"].Value does not print 555.666 in the below example.

Because the dictionary's index `[]` operator returns `BaseClass`, the only kind of `Value` the compiler knows is the one of type `string`. The `double Value` property does not override it - it is in addition to the `string` one.

> I'm trying to create a dictionary of classes that could return different types

Use an interface instead of a base class, put a property of type `object`, and put different implementations, like this:

```
interface WithValue {
    object Value {get;set;}
}
public ClassA : WithValue {
    private string _value;
    object Value {
        get {return _value;}
        set {_value = (string)value;}
    }
}
public ClassB : WithValue {
    private double _value;
    object Value {
        get {return _value;}
        set {_value = (double)value;}
    }
}
```

Now your code from the `Main` should work fine:

```
Dictionary<string,WithValue> zList = new Dictionary<string,WithValue>();
ClassA zA = new ClassA();
zA.Value = "Test";
zList["A"] = zA;

ClassB zB = new ClassB();
zB.Value = 555.666;
zList["B"] = zB;

Console.WriteLine(zList["A"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(zList["B"].Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are are using `new` in your property definition of `Value`. You want to make your `Value` on `BaseClass` `virtual` and then `override` on `ClassB`.

Basically, what is happening is that you are hiding the base's `Value` property with your own and when it gets called on the base, it doesn't actually have a value because it doesn't contain the `ClassB._value` field or `ClassB.Value` property.

EDIT:
I missed that you were also declaring a different type. You cannot override and give a different type. You need to come up with a different name or mechanism for returning a specific type if you want to call it from the base class. You may want to look into using Generics to do what you want and have a `public T Value {get;set;}`  property on your base class instead.

Comment: @JleruOHeP Whoops. Sorry, I completely missed the property was given a different type. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `Dictionary` has type of the `BaseClass`. Thus it infers that you are looking for the `Value` that's declared in the `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Base class does not have access to the derived class property, the value displayed is that of the baseclass (which is null). Consider the following code to be able to display the required value...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Dictionary<string, BaseClass> zList = new Dictionary<string, BaseClass>();
        ClassA zA = new ClassA();
        zA.Value = "Test";
        zList["A"] = zA;

        ClassB zB = new ClassB();
        zB.Value = 555.666;
        zList["B"] = zB;


        Console.WriteLine(zList["A"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine(zList["B"].Value);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    protected string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}

public class ClassA : BaseClass
{

}

public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    private new double _value1;

    public new double Value
    {
        get { return _value1; }
        set { _value1 = value; _value = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Good Luck!